# DAX to calculate the average for all 7 days Quantity value

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
|  DateTime             |    Quantity   |
|:--------------------- |:   ---------- |
| 6/8/2021  1:00PM      |      89       |
| 6/7/2021  8:00PM      |      99       |
| 6/6/2021  11:00PM     |      70       |
| 6/5/2021  9:00PM      |      60       |
| 6/4/2021  5:00AM      |      55.5     |
| 6/3/2021  11:00PM     |      53       |
| 6/2/2021  12:00AM     |      99       |
| 6/1/2021  6:00PM      |      100      |

I tried the following code but not giving me the correct result. There are two varaibles. Not sure if it's correct way.
"Average Last 7 Days= 
var All_Hours= CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Table1[Quantity]), ALLSELECTED(Table1))
var lastOneWeek = LastOneHour - TIME(168,0,0) '''168 is for the past '''7 days hour.
```

return CALCULATE([Quantity] , FILTER(ALL(Table1), SystemMetrics[timestamp]>=All_Hours))" Much appreiated for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to calculate AVERAGE for 7 days started now? Or for the last 7 days ended on each DateTime?

```
AVG7dayNOW = 
Calculate (AVERAGE(Table1[Quantity]), FILTER(ALL(Table1[DateTime]), Table1[DateTime] >= NOW() - 7 && Table1[DateTime] <= NOW()))
```

Second hit:

```
AVG7Day =
calclulate (AVERAGE(Table1[Quantity]), FILTER(ALL(Table1[DateTime]), Table1[DateTime] >= SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[DateTime]) - 7 && Table1[DateTime] <= SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[DateTime])))
```

You can change ALL to ALLSELECTED if you want to apply other filters.